# getElementById where ID increases by 1

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm making a website where I present information gathered by APIs. I'm trying to display the weather for today and tomorrow for a specific country. However, I receive the notification that Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementById' of null. So I think the problem is lying in the ID I'm trying to refer to.

In index.html:

```
<div id="weather">
<div id="day1">
<div id="weatherIcon"></div>
<div id="weatherDescription"></div>
<div id="temp"></div>
<div id="humidity"></div>
<div id="speed"></div>
</div>
<div id="day2">
<div id="weatherIcon"></div>
<div id="weatherDescription"></div>
<div id="temp"></div>
<div id="humidity"></div>
<div id="speed"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

In the JavaScript file:

```
                var openWeather = result.openWeather;
                document.getElementById("tempUnits").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("windUnits").style.display = "block";

                document.querySelector("#country_weather").innerText = "Weather in " + openCage.results[0].components.country;

                for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) { 

                    const description = openWeather.daily[i].weather[0].description;
                    const temp = openWeather.daily[i].temp.day;
                    const humidity = openWeather.daily[i].humidity;
                    const speed = openWeather.daily[i].wind_speed;

                    document.getElementById(('day' + (i + 1))).getElementById('weatherIcon').attr('src', `http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${openWeather.daily[i].weather[0].icon}@2x.png`);
                    document.getElementById(('day' + (i + 1))).getElementById('weatherDescription').html(description);
                    document.getElementById(('day' + (i + 1))).getElementById('temp').html(temp);
                    document.getElementById(('day' + (i + 1))).getElementById('humidity').html(humidity + "%");
                    document.getElementById(('day' + (i + 1))).getElementById('windSpeed').html(speed);
                }
```

Comment: What “main file” are you talking about here? You should provide a _proper_ [mre] with questions like this, always.

Comment: It maybe possible that its trying to check day01 instead of day1. Console log this line just after your loop starts document.getElementById(('day' + (i + 1))). If that's the case then use eval(i+1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementById' of null

That means that somewhere you are doing `null.getElementById`.

Probably one of these lines (that are wrong anyway):

```
document.getElementById(('day' + (i + 1))).getElementById('weatherIcon')
```

The first part doesn't find any HTML element and returns `null`, then the second part tries to call `null.getElementById`.

The problem with that line is that an `id` must be *unique* within the DOM. Neve to appear twice within the same HTML document. So trying to look up the `id` within a sub-group of the HTML `.getElementById('weatherIcon')` doesn't make sense, because it must be unique in the **entire** document.

Repeated identifiers like `weatherIcon` should be `class`es instead.

```
let dayElem = document.getElementById(('day' + (i + 1)));

dayElem.getElementsByClassName('weatherIcon')[0].attr(...);
dayElem.getElementsByClassName('weatherDescription')[0].html(...);
dayElem.getElementsByClassName('temp')[0].html(temp);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById(('day' + (i + 1))).getElementById('weatherIcon').attr('src', `http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${openWeather.daily[i].weather[0].icon}@2x.png`);
```

This line of code is not working because you don't have `<div id="weatherIcon">` in your html file for the divs with id `day1` and `day2`

Answer (score 0):

You should check for existence of an element before you query it further. Element id's in a document must be unique, so in this [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) I used [data-attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

```js
let days = 3;
for (let i = 1; i < days; i += 1) {
  const description = `This is day ${i}`;
  const dayElem = document.querySelector(`#day${i}`);
  if (dayElem) {
    const descriptionElem = dayElem.querySelector("[data-description]");
    if (descriptionElem) {
      descriptionElem.textContent = description;
    }
  }
}

// smarter
for (let i = 1; i < days; i += 1) {
  const dayElemTemp = document.querySelector(`#day${i} [data-temp]`);
  if (dayElemTemp) {
    dayElemTemp.textContent = `It will be ${
      (1 + Math.random() * 30).toFixed(1)} degrees celcius`;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="weather">
  <div id="day1">
    <div data-description></div>
    <div data-temp></div>
  </div>
  <div id="day2">
    <div data-description></div>
    <div data-temp></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

IDs have to be unique per page, you cannot have IDs with same name. getElementById function is gonna fail in case if there are id with same name.

You have to use the class property

```
<div id="weather">
<div id="day1">
<div class="weatherIcon"></div>
<div class="weatherDescription"></div>
<div class="temp"></div>
<div class="humidity"></div>
<div class="speed"></div>
</div>
<div id="day2">
<div class="weatherIcon"></div>
<div class="weatherDescription"></div>
<div class="temp"></div>
<div class="humidity"></div>
<div class="speed"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

then access elements later like that

```
document.getElementById(('day' + (i+ 1))).getElementsByClassName('weatherIcon')[0].attr('src', `http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${openWeather.daily[i].weather[0].icon}@2x.png`);
```

Comment: Would this be possible if you're using Bootstrap for design purposes?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for all your help!! It really helped to get a fresh set of eyes on my work! In the end, it was a very basic mistake. I had multiple values with the same id (forgot that you couldn't do that - sorry bit of a newbie!) Anyways I changed all my ids to like so:

In index.html:

```
id="day_1_temp";
^^^ etc.
```

Then in javascript like so:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) { 

                    const description = openWeather.daily[i].weather[0].description;
                    const celsius_temp = (openWeather.daily[i].temp.day).toFixed(2);
                    const fahrenheit_temp = ((celsius_temp * 1.8) + 32).toFixed(2);
                    const speed_ms = (openWeather.daily[i].wind_speed).toFixed(2);
                    const speed_mph = (speed_ms * 2.237).toFixed(2);
                    const humidity = openWeather.daily[i].humidity;

                    document.querySelector('#tempUnits' + (i + 1)).style.display = "block";
                    document.querySelector('#windUnits' + (i + 1)).style.display = "block";
                    document.querySelector("#day_" + (i + 1) + "_icon").setAttribute('src', `http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${openWeather.daily[i].weather[0].icon}@2x.png`);
                    document.querySelector("#day_" + (i + 1) + "_description").innerHTML = description;
                    document.querySelector("#day_" + (i + 1) + "_temp").style.display = "none";
                    document.querySelector("#day_" + (i + 1) + "_temp_celsius").style.display = "block";
                    document.querySelector("#day_" + (i + 1) + "_temp_celsius").innerHTML = celsius_temp;
                    document.querySelector("#day_" + (i + 1) + "_temp_fahrenheit").innerHTML = fahrenheit_temp;
                    document.querySelector("#day_" + (i + 1) + "_humidity").innerHTML = (humidity + " %");
                    document.querySelector("#day_" + (i + 1) + "_speed").style.display = "none";
                    document.querySelector("#day_" + (i + 1) + "_speed_ms").style.display = "block";
                    document.querySelector("#day_" + (i + 1) + "_speed_ms").innerHTML = speed_ms;
                    document.querySelector("#day_" + (i + 1) + "_speed_mph").innerHTML = speed_mph;
                }
```